# DIY IR spectrometry - stray light (higher orders diffraction maxima)

Tags: spectroscopy, infrared-radiation

Context: homemade IR spectrometer with diffraction grating.

Since

$$m \lambda = d \sin \Theta _{m}$$

diffraction maxima of higher orders from shorter wavelengths will be mixed with lower order maxima for longer wavelengths.
For example order 2 for $\frac{\lambda}{2}$ with order 1 for $\lambda$.

This means I cannot simply associate given $\Theta$ with one wavelength.

How can I solve this problem using DIY methods?

Comment: Usually one uses [monochromatic light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochrome), so there's only one $\lambda$ to be concerned about. As for DIY methods, I'm not sure but I imagine there are filters you could purchase.

Comment: You set up the geometry of the given grating and detector so that you don't have significant overlap of orders across the spectrum of interest.